# Composition of polynomial and multiplicative is multiplicative .

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, function-and-relation-composition, multiplicative-function

I made the following problem a while ago but I can't solve it (also I don't think it's extremely hard ) :

> Let $f$ be a non-constant completely multiplicative function over $\mathbb{Z}$ . Assume that there is some non-constant polynomial $P \in Z[X]$  such that $P \circ f $ is also a completely multiplicative function . Then prove that $P$ is a monomial (something like $P(x)=ax^m$ ) .

If you want a challenge then replace **completely multiplicative** with just **multiplicative** . Also you can try with $f \circ P$ instead of $P \circ f$ (though I think this makes the problem simpler )

This is easily one of my favorites problems (partly because I came with it myself ) but I couldn't solve it .

Thanks for all the help .

**EDIT** 
In response to **user270395**'s answer I'll add the additional condition :

> $$f(n) \neq 0$$ for every $n \neq 0$ .

I hope this suffices .

**EDIT 2** 
I feel embarrassed that my previous two problems had counter-examples but I think the following new condition is strong enough to get past the "trivial" counter-examples (thanks to **EricWong** for his thoughts)  :

> $f(n)$ takes an infinite number of different values and all are non-zero (except $f(0)=0$) .

Comment: Could you clarify whether $P\circ f$ means $P(f(\cdot))$ or $f(P(\cdot))$?  As you describe, the problem makes sense either way,

Comment: Yes . I created it with $P(f(x))$ but I guess that it works the other way too .

Comment: The non-vanishing condition still isn't strong enough.  You probably need something that forces $f$ to take *infinitely* many distinct values.

Comment: Yes this seems to be the only way. Do you have a suggestion for such a condition?

Comment: For the completely multiplicative case and $P(f(\cdot))$ version, I expect it suffices to require $f(n) \not\in \{0,\pm 1\}$ for one arbitrary $n$.  If $f$ is just multiplicative, then you probably need infinitely many such $n$ (with some sort of independence property).  The $f(P(\cdot))$ version may well be more interesting, but I haven't thought about it enough.

Comment: What would "solving" this problem mean to you?  Apparently you aren't just interested in knowing whether the claim is true or false.  It sounds more like you want to know sufficient conditions to make it true: if so, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @EricWong At first I thought this problem "should" be true with the exception of some special cases . After some "verifications" I thought that the non-constant condition suffices but because there are counterexamples I need to change the conditions . I'll change it to a stronger condition and hope for a proof . Thanks for your time .

Answer (score 2):

Its not true. Let $f(\pm 1)=1$ and $f(n)=0$ for all other $n$. Let $P(x)=x^2-x+1$ then $P(f(x))=1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Ok , ok fine . Let's make the additional condition that $f(n) \neq 0$ for every $n \neq 0$ . Good luck finding a counterexample for that :).

Comment: @ComplexPhi Still not true: let $f(n) = \lambda(n)$ or any other non-trivial $\pm1$-valued completely multiplicative function.  Then choose $P(x) = x^3-x+1$ so that $P(f(n)) = 1$ for all $n$.